# how to find address using these api i write this code for find the address using this api ket

Tags: api, key

```
Controller page

.controller('SomeController', function (SomeDataFactory,$scope,$state) {
    var _this = this;
    var latitude;
    var longitude;
    var radious;
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.address = function ($scope) {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

                latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                radious = 10;
            });
            console.log(latitude);
            console.log(longitude);
            console.log(radious);
        }
    }

    SomeDataFactory.getSomeData(latitude, longitude, radious).then(function (response) {
        alert(response);
        //do something with response
        _this.data = response.data;
    }).catch(function (response) {
        //handle the error
    });
});


Service.js page

.factory('SomeDataFactory', function ($http) {
    var url = 'http://192.168.1.100:2016/Ionic_AppServices.svc/?Addresss';

    return {
        getSomeData: function () {
            return $http.jsonp(url);
        }
    }
});
```

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude of my position using AngularJS and Geolocation. This is the function in the controller in which I am assigning the values of the latitude and the longitude and printing them out to the browser console. The address() function is called,